# How to get AWS Availability zone in Cloud formation dynamically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Recently I have started exploring the AWS CloudFormation. I have one doubt to use  Fn::GetAZs to get Availability Zone dynamically ? I want the Availability Zone not to be hardcoded.
The code in YAML format is as follows :-

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Hardcoded Value of Availability zone
Parameters: 
 MyKeyName:
  Description: Arshan Select the key Name from the boelow 
  Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
 MyZone:
  Description: Select the MyAZone
  Type: String
  Default: us-east-1
  AllowedValues:
  - us-east-1
  - us-east-2
Resources:
 DevEC2Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
   InstanceType: t2.micro
   ImageId: ami-04aa88aebb9fefd83
   KeyName: !Ref MyKeyName 
   SecurityGroup: !Ref SSHSecurityGroup
   AvailabilityZone: !Ref MyZone
 SSHSecurityGroup:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup 
  Properties: 
   GroupDescription: My Sg
   SecurityIngress:
    IpProtocol: tcp
    ToPort: 22
    FromPort: 22
    Cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
   SecurityEgress:
    IpProtocol: tcp 
    ToPort: 8080
    FromPort: 8080
    Cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: What is your question? Use `AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs ]`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getavailabilityzones.html

Comment: @jarmod My question is I wanted to use  Fn::GetAZs, to return a value of availability zone then select any AZ from it

Comment: What problem are you having using Fn::GetAZs?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following in the parameters section:

AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name

So something like:
MyZone:
Description: Select the MyAZone
Type: AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name

Then in your resources section use !Ref MyZone
This will take the user selected value from the parameters section.

Useful doc here:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Fn::GetAZs` in your Parameter  `MyZone` to define allowed AZs, then you can't do this. Such a thing is **not supported** by CloudFormation. Your `MyZone` must **hardcode** the AZs you want to allow.

`Fn::GetAZs` can be used in your Resources later on, but not in `MyZone` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your helping hands. Now I am using Fn::GetAzs in Resources section which is
AvailabilityZone: !Select 
        - 0
        - !GetAZs 
          Ref: 'AWS::Region'