# Shorten function to select AWS Availability Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there any way we can shorten this function to select the availability group?

This is the long function to get and select the availability group:

############

```
AvailabilityZone: !Select 
  - 0
  - !GetAZs 
    Ref: 'AWS::Region'
```

##########

I'm trying to convert this into one liner to select the availability group dynamically - which currently hardcoded as** "ap-southeast-2b"**under Dimensions)

###########

```
 MetricStat:
    Metric:
      MetricName: ReceivedPackets
      Namespace: AWS/NetworkFirewall
      Dimensions:
        - Name: FirewallName
          Value: NetworkFirewall,"AvailabilityZone","**ap-southeast-2b**", "Engine", "Stateful
    Period: 300
    Stat: Average
```

############

tried this but didnt work

```
Value: NetworkFirewall,"AvailabilityZone", !Select - {{0}} - !GetAZs Ref: 'AWS::Region', "Engine", "Stateful"
```

Tried other suggestion here but looks not working to me [How to get AWS Availability zone in Cloud formation dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922074/how-to-get-aws-availability-zone-in-cloud-formation-dynamically)